# Hiding FullScreen MediaElement

Tags: mediaelement.js

How do I hide the fullscreen option from the flash-video control panel? The flash version that I have plays in IE 7-8 and Safari. I can remove the fullscreen button for browsers that use the other formats, no problem. I have tried using the `<param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" />` within my `object` tag, but there is no effect.

Are there any easy ways to customize the Flash video controls.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing `fullscreen` from the features configration parameter:

```
features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume']
```

See section 4 on http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: That only works for the non-Flash videos, ie the OGM, MP4, and WEBM versions of the video.

Comment: I think that would qualify as a bug on mediaelement as it shouldn't make a difference how things are being played back.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the browser version and show/hide the full screen icon from mediaelement player configuration while initiating the player.

```
$('video, audio').mediaelementplayer({
    // if the <video width> is not specified, this is the default
    defaultVideoWidth: 480,
    // if the <video height> is not specified, this is the default
    defaultVideoHeight: 270,
    // if set, overrides <video width>
    videoWidth: -1,
    // if set, overrides <video height>
    videoHeight: -1,
    // width of audio player
    audioWidth: 30,
    // height of audio player
    audioHeight: 400,
    // initial volume when the player starts
    startVolume: 0.8,
    // useful for <audio> player loops
    loop: false,
    // enables Flash and Silverlight to resize to content size
    enableAutosize: false,
    // the order of controls you want on the control bar (and other plugins below)
    //We are not showing "fullscreen" control in IE8 or lower as it does not work in IE8
    features: ( navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE 8.0') > 0 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE 7.0') > 0) ? ["playpause", "progress", "current", "duration", "tracks", "volume"] : ["playpause", "progress", "current", "duration", "tracks", "volume", "fullscreen"],

    //...
    //Other configurations go here
    //...
});
```